# Conditional css showing limit items

Tags: css

Says I have 10 `<p>`, how to limit them to 5 by hiding another 5 using css? do I have to do 5 times of class like nth-child? Would it be possible to use condition in css? Because the numbers of `<p>` is dynamic, it can be 20, 30, or 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `nth-child(n+x)` selector such as:

```
p:nth-child(n+6) {
  display:none;  
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyberwombat/rvrtf0hy/) demonstrating with the color red for 6+

`n+6` is an abbreviation for the formula equation `an+b` (see [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) and [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)) which is iterated through for every values of "n" that are >=0 and where a and b are integers >0. So the full formula in this case it is equivalent:

```
1n+6
```

Which for values of `n` as 0,1.. would give: 6,7... matching the 6th and up tags.

By modifying `b` we are able to create intervals such as:

```
2n+6
```

Which for values of n as 0,1 now yields 6, 8, 10 and so on, effectively matching every other `p` tag starting from the 6th one.

Comment: Actually this is a better answer than mine since this is solely css.

Comment: what is n here stand for?

Comment: @dfox I've updated my answer with some explanation and links to bedtime reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to jquery you can use: `$('p:gt(5)').hide();` which will hide all `<p>` elements after the 5th one.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Adding to the accepted answer.

**Define a range** - selecting elements between `2 to 10`.

```
:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+10)
```

**Select even elements in that range.**

```
:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+10):nth-child(even)
```

**Select odd elements in that range.**

```
:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+10):nth-child(odd)
```

The evaluation of the formula `an+b` follows [**Operator Precedence**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and its value is always a **non-negative whole number.**

*Note: You can't divide or add decimals in that formula.*